# Flows sending out emails

Tags: workflow

I have created a flow when, a file is modified.. However the emails are sending out every second.
How do I stop this from happening?

Any sugguestions.
I only want to send an email when the ticket is closed.
So the customer is informed about their case.

Comment: Add conditions via the trigger's Settings, and/or put the email action inside a condition action

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is what I created.   Which the conditions are: Status Eq Closed then send an email. But for some reason it started to keep on sending the emails out. it was working fine before.